# Symfony @QueryParam requirements

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I have the following method with annotation:

```
class ProjectController extends FOSRestController
{
 /////
* @QueryParam(name="status", strict=true, requirements="[a-z]+", description="status of project", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="skill", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z ^0-9().,+]+", description="skill of project", nullable=true)
 * @QueryParam(name="close", requirements="\d+", description="project by close")
 * @QueryParam(name="main_skill", strict=true, requirements="^[a-zA-Z ^0-9().,+]+", description="project by main_skill", nullable=true)
```

but if I have `skill` or `main_skill` C++ and in debug I see `query->main_skill="C "` or if I need C# in debug I have only "C", what need add to requirements?

Answer (score 0):

for C++ try this : requirements="^[a-zA-Z ^0-9().,\+]+"

Comment: not help from debug query="C " and for C# query="C "